# x86: Triple fault on call instruction after switching page directory

Tags: x86, kernel, qemu, osdev, xv6

I've been building my version of the xv6 OS, but just as I switch to a newly created page directory and try to call a function, it triple faults.

A lot of similar questions have been asked and usually the problem is that a page fault is not correctly handled, either because of incorrect page mapping or incorrect IDT.

In my case I've manually checked the mapping and it works, so I'm out of ideas what else can be broken. See below for details.

Here's where I am in the kernel (just switched CR3 to the new page table and about to call `test_function`):

```
   │0x801017ad <kernel_start+29>    call   0x80101040 <init_kernel_memory_range>
   │0x801017b2 <kernel_start+34>    call   0x801013c0 <init_global_kernel_page_dir>
   │0x801017b7 <kernel_start+39>    call   0x80101390 <switch_to_kernel_page_dir> 
  >│0x801017bc <kernel_start+44>    call   0x80101770 <test_function>
```

I can verify in gdb that the memory of `test_function` is accessible, so the mapping seems to be correct:

```
(gdb) x/10i test_function

0x80101770 <test_function>:          push   ebp
0x80101771 <test_function+1>:        mov    ebp,esp
0x80101773 <test_function+3>:        sub    esp,0x8
0x80101776 <test_function+6>:        lea    eax,ds:0x80101b00
0x8010177c <test_function+12>:       mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x8010177f <test_function+15>:       call   0x80101750 <panic>
0x80101784 <test_function+20>:       add    esp,0x8
0x80101787 <test_function+23>:       pop    ebp
0x80101788 <test_function+24>:       ret
0x80101789:  nop
```

I can also verify that the stack can be accessed:

```
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0x8010101c       0x8010101c

(gdb) x/10w 0x8010101c
0x8010101c:     0x80104024      0x80400000      0x00007bf8      0x90669066
0x8010102c:     0x90669066      0x8be58955      0xc35d0845      0x90909090
0x8010103c:     0x90909090      0x83e58955
```

The identity mapping of low addresses to physical that used to be in the previous page directory no longer exists, and that is intended (`0x101770` is the physical address of `test_function`):

```
(gdb) x/10i 0x101770
0x101770:    Cannot access memory at address 0x101770
```

I have also manually verified that the addresses I care about are correctly translated using the page directory / page table into physical addresses. Yet when I finally `call test_function`, I get this in QEMU:

```
EAX=003ff000 EBX=00010094 ECX=003ff000 EDX=fe000000
ESI=00010094 EDI=00000000 EBP=80101024 ESP=8010101c
EIP=801017bc EFL=00000096 [--S-AP-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
GS =0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007c60 00000017
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=80010011 CR2=00000040 CR3=003ff000 CR4=00000010
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
EFER=0000000000000000
Triple fault.  Halting for inspection via QEMU monitor.
```

IDT is not yet set up, but I'm not expecting any page faults yet.

Anything that I'm missing here? **What else can cause a triple fault?** Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in BOCHS?  I've heard its built-in debugger can tell you more about faults, and show you page-table info.  That would let you double-check that the right stuff is in page tables and GDT.

Comment: @PeterCordes I haven't yet, but I will if it's not something obvious that I missed that people can point to easily. Didn't know it can show page table info, that's useful!

Comment: I think it's highly recommended enough by other Stack Overflow regulars for osdev in general that it's probably worth your time to get it set up, whether or not you need it for this specific problem.

Comment: Run qemu with additional options `-no-shutdown -no-reboot -d int` until the program fails. Then put all of the output into a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and share a link to it here. There will be exception information that may be useful to see what the cause of the fault was (lines with `v=` and `e=` give exception and error code information).

Comment: It is also worth checking `info tlb` in the QEMU monitor (or `monitor info tlb` in the gdb interface, if it's still functional) when you get triple fault to see QEMU's idea of the TLB state.

Comment: @MichaelPetch here it is https://pastebin.com/y10kVz9x. Not sure how to decipher it just yet. Maybe it's more obvious to you. I couldn't google anything sensible on "v=0e e=0003".

Comment: Looking at the debug output in the pastebin this information is noteworthy: `0: v=0e e=0003 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:801017bc pc=801017bc SP=0010:8010101c CR2=80101018` . Exception `v=0e` (hex) is a page fault. `e=0003` is error code 3 for a page fault. Bit 0 in page fault error code mean that it was caused by a page protection violation and Bit 1 being set means it was caused by a write access. CR2 (0x80101018) is the virtual address that caused the fault. So it looks like the call instruction attempted to push the return address on the stack on a page that it doesn't have write privs to do so

Comment: You can find more on deciphering the error codes in the Intel Software development manuals, but there is a good summary on the OSDev wiki: https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions#Page_Fault . It appears that you your page structures (page directory and or page table) associated with the area of the stack is set to read only.

Comment: After you set the new page  structure by updating CR3 you can use the GDB monitor's `info pg` to dump the page table structure and `info tlb` to dump the translation lookahead buffer. That information may help you determine what may be wrong. `info mem` will dump the mapped virtual memory and permissions but unlike `info pg` it doesn't separate out the page entries and page tables.

Comment: If you provided the output of `info tlb` and `info pg` in the QEMU monitor right after you set CR3 (but before the page fault) we might be able to see the problem. In GDB when doing a remote debug in QEMU you should be able to also use the `monitor info tlb` and `monitor info pg` commands to send the remote monitor in QEMU the commands and get a response.

Comment: @MichaelPetch omg you're absolutely right. The stack was pointing to the area adjacent to the kernel text/data, which was read only. I just set the write flag in that portion of the map and it worked. In hindsight it's obvious, but I was totally stuck and out of ideas :) If you could put this in an answer I would accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPetch I found the reason why my stack was in the readonly section - I was looking at the xv6 GAS code and translated it to NASM, and they allocate memory for the stack using the `.comm` directive. What I didn't realise is that .comm allocates memory in the `.data` section. I just used `stack resb STACK_SIZE` and ended up allocating space in the `.text` section, where the kernel was. It worked up until the point where I switched the page mapping. Thanks again for helping to figure this out!